# curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer - Docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am getting below error:

```
$ docker container run -d --name web -p 9090:9090 -v `pwd`/webapp.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/webapp.war jboss/wildfly
4be6d47c7e6d923fef1d04e12edd6365bdd4fe0087844018b3e5a6b0f6e0c12c

$ docker container ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
4be6d47c7e6d        jboss/wildfly       "/opt/jboss/wildfl..."   15 seconds ago      Up 14 seconds       8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp   web

$ curl http://localhost:9090/webapp/resources/persons
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you run your service as `0.0.0.0:{port}` rather than `127.0.0.1:{port}`.

Answer (score 3):

The docker you are using listens on ports 8080 and 8443.

For more details run:
`docker logs web`

Instead of running with:
`-p 9090:9090`

Run it with:

`-p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443`

Then you can:

`curl localhost:8080`

Or open in your browser:

http://localhost:8080/